# Prevent User from creating instance for other users

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication

I have 4 models each related to each other with ForeignKey.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField() //business name
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name=businesses,on_del=models.CASCADE)

class ProdCategory(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business,related_name=categories,on_del=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField()

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProdCategory,related_name=products,on_del=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey()
    price = models.DecimalField()
```

Now If I try to get all the Products of the current authenticated user I get the Correct List of products (that coming from the same User>Business>ProdCategory>Product)

But if I try to create a Product with authenticated user, I can create a Product with providing the id of ProdCategory(already created by different users)
(User of Business>ProdCategory) != self.request.user

In Short I can create product for other users. Which is not what I want.
I want to prevent the current user from creating products if ProdCategory id provided is of different users. It should return error. User must provide the id of ProdCategory that was created by the same user.

> ***Serializer classes are defined with all fields using ModelSerializer.***

Here goes the View for creating and listing products:

```
class CategoryItemListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategoryItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CategoryItem.objects.filter(category__budget__created_by=self.request.user).order_by('order')
    
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        item_data = response.data   
        # there will be multiple categories for One business 
        categories = ProdCategory.objects.filter(business__created_by=request.user)
        for c in categories:
            if item_data['category'] == c.id:
                Product.objects.create(name=item_data['name'], category=item_data['category'])
        return response
```

I updated the view with overriding the create method. Now it's letting me create Product for other users if I pass category ID of the other users. But when I pass category id of requesting users category it throws error saying category fields should be instance of ProdCategory not "3". (3 is the id of a ProdCategory)
but if I pass {"category": 1} it creates Product. (1 is the id of ProdCategory created by other users)

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically What I wanted is to prevent the user from pushing Product to ProdCategory that is not own by the user.

I just found a solution.
so I'm adding this here in case anybody else come across the same issue.

to prevent the user I added a validation for category in Product serializer. Overriding the create method is not necessary.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def validate_category(self, value):
        category_id = value.id
        category = ProdCategory.objects.get(id=category_id)
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if category.business.created_by != user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("You do not have permission")
        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your `create product` side. So I just write the logic.

```
prodCategory= ProdCategory.objects.get(id=1)
if prodCategory.business.created_by == request.user:
     #let user to create the product
     Product.objects.create()
else:
    return False
```

I hope you understand the logic

Comment: I updated the question with full view class. Would you please take a look into that?